# Spring security, error 405 with protecting current post method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I use spring security with roles to protect current pages or actions with their own addresses of my application. With access denied page i can catch page of error 403 (access denied) when user tries to
get not allowed page, but when i protect current action, like this:

```
<form th:action="'/blog/'+${el.id}+'/remove'" method="post">
                    <button class = "btn btn-warning" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
```

With current controller's method:

```
@PostMapping("/blog/{id}/remove")
    public String blogPostRemove(@PathVariable(value = "id") long postId, Model model) {
        Post post = postRepository.findById(postId).orElseThrow();
        postRepository.delete(post);
        return "redirect:/blog";
    }
```

When user with not allowed role tries to act he will get page with error 405:
*There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported*. User with allowed role doesn't have any problem. There is a WebSecurityConfig code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/unpublished","/blog/*/remove","/blog/*/comments/*/remove")
                .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/blog/*/edit","/blog/*/comment","/blog/add").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/","/registration","/login","/blog/*").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

How can i change this page with my /access-denied?
Logs:

```
2020-07-13 11:26:58.094 DEBUG 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/blog/28", parameters={}
2020-07-13 11:26:58.096 DEBUG 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.springExample.controllers.BlogController#blogDetails(long, Model)
2020-07-13 11:26:58.364 DEBUG 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, *//*;q=0.8]
2020-07-13 11:26:58.402 DEBUG 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-07-13 11:27:04.814 DEBUG 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for POST "/access-denied", parameters={}
2020-07-13 11:27:04.816  WARN 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
2020-07-13 11:27:04.817 DEBUG 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 405
2020-07-13 11:27:04.818 DEBUG 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
2020-07-13 11:27:04.818 DEBUG 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2020-07-13 11:27:04.831 DEBUG 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2020-07-13 11:27:04.838 DEBUG 42636 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405
```

Comment: What do you see in the logs when you set `logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG` in application.properties?

Comment: i added logs to post

Comment: Ok, so it's forwarding the original POST to the `/access-denied` resource... Can you post that method as well?

Comment: I understood my problem thanks to your comment, thank you. Solution is posted as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I located the problem - when user tries to act, he will send post method from form. When application catches an access-denied error, it will try to get /access-denied page, but due to action type, it will be post request. Solution is to add PostMapping function of /access-denied page to the current controller:

```
@GetMapping("/access-denied")
public String blockAccess(Model model) {
    return "access-denied";
}

@PostMapping("/access-denied")
public String actionAccess(Model model) {
    return "access-denied";
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `@RequestMapping`, which matches all HTTP methods (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, etc.) if you don't specify the `method = xxx` property.